# What is simple way to read in randomly placed characters line by line?(C++)

Tags: c++, input, inputstream, stdin

[image: sample input]

It should ignore spaces and read in 2 characters.

---

My code to read it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main(){


char current_char1 ;
char current_char2 ;

//input comes from stdin
while(getc() != '\0'){
     current_char1 = getc() ;
     current_char2 = getc() ;                 
  }
```

}

Can you show simpler way to do it?

Comment: 2 characters? So the first line would read `1` and `2`, but ignore the `5`? The easiest way to skip whitespace is [`std::cin >> std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws).

Comment: Don't post images of text! It's impossible to copy if we want to try it out ourselves.

Comment: This is the easiest way @ERJAN according to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 characters"? The first two non-white characters on the line or groupings of 2 characters?

There are various ways to do this. std::getline to get a whole line into a string, then there are various ways to skip whitespace

Comment: Also, [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) (which you call erroneously) will never return the character `'\0'`.

Comment: And finally, the "text" shown contain more than two characters per line, I think you mean "strings"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `getc` sure will return `'\0'` if there is a byte with that value in the file.  The OP seems to have `'\0'` confused with `EOF`...

Comment: How about 123, will you skip that number? Or take first 2, last 2?

Comment: @CodingSiberian, each line contains TWO numbers - there can be many spaces btw them, i need to read 2 numbers per line and store them/process them....

Answer (score 2):

To read two numbers from a single line, no matter the number of spaces, this will be fine:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::istringstream iss(line);

int a, b;
iss >> std::hex >> a >> b;

std::cout << "First value is " << a << ", the second value is " << b << '\n';
```

Comment: This can't be what the OP meant, because the second line of their sample file has an "A" on it.

Comment: @Zack Okay, strings then. Could be hexadecimal though. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, this is actually hex number i must convert to decimal!

Comment: @ERJAN Updated answer to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing C++, but nonetheless, many tasks are easier with `stdio.h` than `iostream`, and this is one of them.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using std::string;

// Returns the next two non-`isspace` characters as a std::string.
// If there aren't that many before EOF, returns all that there are.
// Note: line boundaries ('\n') are ignored just like all other whitespace.
string
read_next_two_nonspace(FILE *fp)
{
    string s;
    int c;

    do c = getc(fp);
    while (c != EOF && isspace(c));
    if (c != EOF) s.append(1, c);

    do c = getc(fp);
    while (c != EOF && isspace(c));
    if (c != EOF) s.append(1, c);

    return s;
}
```

EDIT: If what you actually want is to read two *hexadecimal numbers* from a line-oriented file that is supposed to have two such numbers per line and may have random amounts of whitespace around them, then this is my preferred method.  Joachim's method is shorter, but less reliable; in particular, iostreams *cannot be used safely for numeric input* (!) owing to their being defined in terms of `scanf`, which **provokes undefined behavior** (!!) upon numeric overflow.  This is more code but handles arbitrarily malformed input.  Again, note free mixing of C++ and C library facilities -- there is no reason not to use the older library if it does what you need, as it does in this case.

Preamble:

```
#include <istream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using std::getline;
using std::invalid_argument;
using std::istream;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct two_numbers { unsigned long a; unsigned long b; };
```

Parser:

```
#define isspace_or_eol(c) (isspace(c) || (c) == '\0')

// Parse a line consisting of two hexadecimal numbers, separated and surrounded
// by arbitrary whitespace.
two_numbers
parse_line(string const &s)
{
    const char *p;
    char *endp;
    two_numbers val;

    // N.B. strtoul skips *leading* whitespace.
    errno = 0;
    p = s.c_str();
    val.a = strtoul(p, &endp, 16);
    if (endp == p || !isspace_or_eol(*endp) || errno)
        throw invalid_argument("first number is missing, malformed, or too large");

    p = endp;
    val.b = strtoul(p, &endp, 16);
    if (endp == p || !isspace_or_eol(*endp) || errno)
        throw invalid_argument("second number is missing, malformed, or too large");

    // Verify only whitespace after the second number.
    p = endp;
    while (isspace(*p)) p++;
    if (*p != '\0')
        throw invalid_argument("junk on line after second number");

    return val;
}
```

Example usage:

```
vector<two_numbers>
read_file(istream &fp, const char *fname)
{
    string line;
    unsigned int lineno = 0;
    vector<two_numbers> contents;
    bool erred = false;

    while (getline(fp, line))
    {
        lineno++;
        try
        {
            contents.append(parse_line(line));
        }
        catch (invalid_argument &e)
        {
            std::cerr << fname << ':' << lineno << ": parse error: " 
                      << e.what() << '\n';
            erred = true;
        }
    }

    if (erred)
        throw invalid_argument("parse errors in file");
    return contents;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the code below, a small modification based on Zack's

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool read(FILE * fp, string * ps)
{
    char c = fgetc(fp);

    if(c == EOF)
        return false;

    if(isspace(c))
    {
        ps->clear();
        return read(fp, ps);
    }

    if(isdigit(c))
    {
        ps->append(1, c);
        if(ps->length() == 2)
            return true;
    }

    return read(fp, ps);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE * file;
    fopen_s(&file, "YOURFILE", "r");
    string s;
    while(read(file, &s))
    {
        cout<<s.c_str()<<endl;
        s.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```